# Memory error in Assembly code with newer version of Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-10.4.2

Can anyone tell me why this code works in Delphi 7, but in version 10.4 it has a memory error?

```pascal
procedure ChatPrintf(ChatPrintMSG: PChar);
var
  ChatPrint: Cardinal;

  procedure ChatPrintASM(ChatPrintMSG: PChar); assembler;
  asm
    lea edx, [ChatPrintMSG]
    push edx
    call [ChatPrint]
    pop edx
  end;
begin
  ChatPrint := $009E0C30;
  ChatPrintASM(ChatPrintMSG);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChatPrintf('it: works');
end;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Comment: Anyhow: In Delphi 2009, strings went from Ansi (1 byte per char) to Unicode (2 bytes per char). That's likely the issue.

Comment: Why are you writing asm code at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He doesn't - again it's a copy without linking the sources: either [this](https://progamercity.net/ghack-requests/7401-hack-priston-tale-brazil.html) or [that](https://www.webcheats.com.br/topic/1771622-pegando-adress-para-chatprinft/). Most likely nothing exists at that address (and/or OP is compiling in 64 bit, should it be Delphi XE2).

Comment: @AmigoJack - That's a good find. I suspect that perhaps he doesn't know pascal.

Comment: There is no good reason to use assembly at all in this code. It can be re-written using pure Pascal, eg: `procedure ChatPrintf(ChatPrintMSG: PAnsiChar); type ChatPrintProc = procedure(Msg: PAnsiChar); cdecl; var ChatPrint: ChatPrintProc; begin ChatPrint := ChatPrintProc($009E0C30); ChatPrint(ChatPrintMSG); end;`

Comment: btw, when you say "memory error", what is the exact message? There is a chance some the newer compiler turns on some flags that Windows support for executable's memory protection. Are you trying to load some other EXE/DLL and modify (hack) its behaviour at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas has mentioned, the default string type has changed.  The easiest way to fix it, is to replace **pchar** with **pansichar**

The new definition would be

```pascal
procedure ChatPrintASM(ChatPrintMSG: PAnsiChar);
```

Comment: i made the changes but i have the same error  " access violation addres "

Comment: I just tried it and that code works for me.  Has it occurred to you that perhaps the **absolute address** that you have assigned to your external procedure is incorrect?

Comment: i use same code on delphi 7 and works but 10.4 get error

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you think that an absolute address will be the same in different versions of the compiler?